# java default Locale is en_US, and it use "," for decimal number

Tags: java, file-io, io

I have this example:

```
    System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());
    int count = 0;
    double sum = 0.0;
    FileWriter fout = new FileWriter("test.txt");
    fout.write("2 3,4 5 6 7,4 9,1 10,5 done");
    fout.close();
    FileReader fin = new FileReader("test.txt");
    Scanner src = new Scanner(fin);
    // Read and sum numbers.
    while (src.hasNext()) {
        if (src.hasNextDouble()) {
            sum += src.nextDouble();
            count++;
        } else {
            String str = src.next();
            if (str.equals("done"))
                break;
            else {
                System.out.println("File format error.");
            }
        }
    }
    src.close();
    System.out.println("Average is " + sum / count);
```

and the output is :
**en_US
Average is 6.2**
my problem is why java use "," instead "." for decimal numbers, I'm on Eng Windows?? because when i use this line

```
fout.write("2 3.4 5 6 7.4 9.1 10.5 done");
```

I get 4: **File format error.** which means that java use "," not "."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that a `Scanner` can have its own locale and in your case it seems to differ from the JVM's default locale that is returned by `Locale.getDefault()`.

To see what locale your `Scanner` is using you can call `src.locale()`.

To set the locale you can use `src.useLocale(Locale.US);`

Try this code and see what it prints:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Default locale: " + Locale.getDefault());
        int count = 0;
        double sum = 0.0;
        FileWriter fout = new FileWriter("test.txt");

        // Character used for the decimal point is '.'
        fout.write("2 3.4 5 6 7.4 9.1 10.5 done");
        fout.close();
        FileReader fin = new FileReader("test.txt");
        Scanner src = new Scanner(fin);

        // Setting locale of Scanner
        System.out.println("Scanner locale before resetting to Locale.US: " + src.locale());
        src.useLocale(Locale.US);
        System.out.println("Scanner locale after resetting: " + src.locale());

        // Read and sum numbers.
        while (src.hasNext()) {
            if (src.hasNextDouble()) {
                sum += src.nextDouble();
                count++;
            } else {
                String str = src.next();
                if (str.equals("done"))
                    break;
                else {
                    System.out.println("File format error.");
                }
            }
        }
        src.close();
        System.out.println("Average is " + sum / count);

    }
```

Comment: it used the french locale. Thanks a lot man, that exactly what I needed, Thanks